# Mp4 on aws s3 is causing excessive gets

Tags: amazon-s3, mp4

We are getting excessive gets after we started hosting our mp4 out of a s3 bucket. It looks like the streaming process is causing 100s of gets for every view of video. Is there something we can change either on s3 or the mp4 to reduce the # of gets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution was that the mp4 was badly transcoded.  Im not 100% sure why but after retranscoding the mp4 it worked a lot better.  I found this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5080) that implied excessive gets could be cause by sound and video being far apart on the mp4.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something we can change either on s3 or the mp4 to reduce the # of gets

Not really, the clients make the get requests, not the server, so there is no server side configuration change to over ride it.

You could disable range requests, but that would negatively impact seeking.